# JQuery карточки div

Tags: jquery

Есть несколько карточек с одинаковыми классами (item).

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

При наведении на конкретный элемент класса *.element*, фон это карточки *.item* должен меняться на красный.

```
$(function() {
    $('.element').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.item').css('background-color', 'red');
    });
});
```

Фон именно той карточки, на которую навели мышь, а меняется на всех элементах класса *.item*.
Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на объект менялся именно фон карточки, на которой он находится?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте контекст `$(this)` и от него берите ближайший элемент с классом `.item`

А ещё меняйте стили через *CSS*, а в *JS* просто ими оперируйте

```js
$(function() {
    $('.element').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.item').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.item').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <div class="element">1</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="element">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `this` для указания на конкретный элемент:

```js
$('.element').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).parents('.item').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```css
.item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.element {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если необходимо обратиться к элементу, стоящему выше? То есть, если .item будет находиться, к примеру, в элементе .new?
Получается следующее: .new -> .item -> .element
При наведении на .element должен измениться фон у .new.

Comment: @MrPikokon, в parents просто меняется .item на .new - там неважно сколько родителей и какая вложенность, главное - соответствие классу